# Python- EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to solve a problem using the following code:

```
def inmobi(t):
    while t:
        li = map(int, raw_input().split())
        n, ans = li[0], li[1:]
        one, two, op = [], [], []
        for e in range(n):
            for i in range(1, n):
                if e + i < n:
                    one.append(ans[e] + ans[e + i])
        two = sorted(one)           
        print two[n-1] - two[n-2]
        t += 1
t = int(raw_input())
inmobi(t)
```

This code gives me the desired output when I run using the Linux shell in Ubuntu. However, when I try running this code using an interpreter provided by a competitive programming website, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/editor_trsource_1438181626_447674.py", line 14, in 
    inmobi(t)               
  File "/tmp/editor_trsource_1438181626_447674.py", line 3, in inmobi
    li = map(int, raw_input().split())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I tried reading the answers of other similar questions, but none of them seemed to work in my case.

Comment: Are you certain the competitive coding website is providing input through stdin? Maybe you need to read from `sys.argv` instead.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, they are providing input using stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assumming according to the competitive programming website, the first line of input is the number of testcases (which is normally the case).

Your issue is basically in line -

```
t += 1
```

Here , you keep increasing the value of `t` , but your while condition is `while t:`  , `t` never goes down and hence while loop never exits, so basically the while loop is an infinite loop and soon after the inputs form the programming competition site get exhausted causing the `EOFError` you are seeing. I have no idea how it worked for you in linux, but it should have went into infinite loop there as well. You should decrease t , not increase it.

```
t -= 1
```

Comment: Glad I could be helpful.